# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params'): React using a class component

Tags: reactjs, api

I want to receive the url parameter `:pokemonIndex` from my App.js to my Pokemon.jsx component as a `const pokemonIndex`. I use a class component and I know there is `useParams()` for a function component but I want to see if there is a solution for a class component. Here is App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import NavBar from './components/layout/NavBar';
import Dashboard from './components/layout/Dashboard';
import Pokemon from './components/pokemon/Pokemon';

import backgroundImage from './pattern.png';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App" style={{ background: `url(${backgroundImage})`}}>
        <NavBar />
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route exact path="/pokemon/:pokemonIndex" element={<Pokemon />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is Pokemon.jsx :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Pokemon extends Component {

    state = {
        name: '',
        pokemonIndex: '',
        imageUrl: ''
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { pokemonIndex } = this.props.match.params; 
      
        
        
        const pokemonUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`;
        const pokemonSpeciesUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${pokemonIndex}/`;

        const pokemonRes = await axios.get(pokemonUrl);

        const name = pokemonRes.data.name; 
        this.setState({ name }); 
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What I want to do is get the id `:pokemonIndex` of the `<Pokemon />` element route and use it in the Pokemon.jsx component (which is the page showing the details of the selected pokemon from the previous page which is the PokemonList.jsx) in the `pokemonUrl` so it can get the pokemon id `:pokemonIndex` selected from one of the cards of the PokemonCard.jsx component generated as list in the PokemonList.jsx component. The goal is to get the correct url of the selected pokemon so I can render the details of the concerned pokemon.

Unfortunately, I get an error which is : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
at Pokemon.componentDidMount

Thanks in advance !
I am new to Stack Overflow so don't bother to ask me to be more or less specific.

Comment: From `react-router` 5.1 it has been recommended to not use `withRouter` and in v6 it has been removed. Without `withRouter` your class component has no way to retrieve the props you are attempting to use (it has no direct connection to the router). You can make your own HOC that wraps your component and uses the hooks available from `react-router` to remake a version of `withRouter` and get the functionality you are after... or swap to a function component and use the hooks directly.

Comment: Yep, you can just use the ```useParams``` hook to access the route parameters.

Comment: I found a solution to get the url id: in Pokemon.jsx I added the lines : `const url = window.location.href;` (which shows the href of the page of the Pokemon.jsx component and `const pokemonIndex = url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 1];` which keeps only the id from the url.